# call getSupportFragmentManager() more than once inside an activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

If inside an activity, i call more than once

```
FragmentManager var1 = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentManager var2 = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
```

var1 and var2 point to the same FragmentManager object or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java#FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager%28%29). Answer is yes. `getSupportFragmentManager()` returns reference to final field which cannot change in given instance of `FragmentActivity`

Answer (score 1):

My answer is yes. But if you don't belive me - you can check it using following code:

```
FragmentManager fr1, fr2;
fr1 = getSupportFragmentManager();
fr2 = getSupportFragmentManager();
Log.d("TAG", fr1 + " "+fr2);
```

09-28 18:35:38.755 D/TAG ( 5058): FragmentManager{42203298 in HomeActivity{42202240}} FragmentManager{42203298 in HomeActivity{42202240}}

42203298 and 42203298  means that this is same object.